# Check for section index titles from table view cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have subclassed UITableViewCell and I need to draw my own disclosure indicator. The position of the disclosure indicator depends on whether or not the table view has section index titles set (the "scroll bar", typically the alphabet).

Does anyone know of a way to check if the table view shows section index titles from the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking this from the `UITableViewCell` subclass would require a big deal of coupling with the `UITableView` class, so I suggest you take an alternate route - add a `BOOL` variable which you set in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` function and then call a function on your cell that will draw the disclosure indicator according to the value of the variable.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. It would have been nice if the cell could know if section index titles are shown, but I understand it might not be reliable (or at least not a good idea). Instead, I ended up doing as you said: setting a `BOOL` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` which describes whether or not te tableview shows section index titles.